# ¿Cómo se usa en onChanges an Angular 2/4 para refrescar la vista?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

Estoy tratando de refrescar los datos de una tabla que se cargan desde una llamada a un API. El API tiene páginas. Creé un botón de `'Next'` para cambiar a la siguiente página y logré obtener los objetos de la segunda página y subsecuentes. Sin embargo, no logro que el ciclo `ngFor` refresque la vista (View) cuando el arreglo de datos recibe nuevos valores. Sé que el `onChange` sirve para refrescar la vista pero no estoy seguro de saber cómo usarlo.

```
ngOnInit() {
    //this.urlPagination = this.urlEmployee;
    this.ngOnChanges(this.urlEmployee);
  }

  ngOnChanges(url) {
    this.http.request(url).subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.data = res.json();

      var rows = this.data['restify']['rows'];

      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
        this.employees.push(new Employee(rows[i]));   
        console.log(rows[i]); 
      }
    });
  }

  clickNext() {
    // two way binding to enable/disable the button
    this.urlPagination = this.urlEmployee + '&_count=20&_expand=yes&_start=20';
    this.ngOnChanges(this.urlPagination);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro por que estas usando el método ngOnChanges, ese método lo puedes implementar para supervisar los cambios en el componente, pero no es necesario ya que angular automáticamente revisa los cambios por tí.
Prueba esto...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.updateData(this.urlEmployee);
}

updateData(url) {
  this.http.request(url).subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.data = res.json();

    var rows = this.data['restify']['rows'];

    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
      this.employees.push(new Employee(rows[i]));   
      console.log(rows[i]); 
    }
  });
}

clickNext() {
  // two way binding to enable/disable the button
  this.urlPagination = this.urlEmployee + '&_count=20&_expand=yes&_start=20';
  this.updateData(this.urlPagination);
}
```

Es lo mismo que hiciste, pero sin usar el ngOnChanges